# Get count of items that matches a condition from mongo db in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am new to mongo db. I have a scenario where I need to check into collection and the count of items having gameDate = current date.
I am using the following query in node js.

```
const count = this.games.find({gameDate:currentDate}).count();
console.log(count + "items present")
```

I have 1 matching record in database. But instead of getting count am getting the following error in console.

```
function(filter, callback) {
  this.op = 'count';
  if (typeof filter === 'function') {
  callback = filter;
  filter = undefined;
  }

 filter = utils.toObject(filter);

 if (mquery.canMerge(filter)) {
  this.merge(filter);
  }

  if (!callback) {
   return this;
  }

  this.exec(callback);

  return this;
 }
```

How can I get the count here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the `countDocuments` function.

```
games.countDocuments({gameDate:currentDate}, function (err, count) {
    if (err){
        console.log(err)
    }else{
        console.log("Total:", count)
    }
});
```